# New Hard Drive in Win10

Tags: windows-10

I had a Win7 install with booting and software on C: and all the \Users\ dirs and files on D:

Now I have installed a new D: drive, but instead of getting a new Users\ dir on D:, I am getting "User profile service cannot start"  and no ID can log in to the machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you may need to recreate your user profiles since the disk change. Use the Command Prompt option in Recovery mode to backup and delete the registry key for a profile.

```
reg export HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\[SID] c:\profile.reg
reg delete HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\[SID]
```

If you copied the actual user folders you'll want to rename or move those as well to avoid overwriting them.